# Iterating dictionary indexes in django templates

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a dictionary with embedded objects, which looks something like this:

```
notes = {
    2009: [<Note: Test note>, <Note: Another test note>],
    2010: [<Note: Third test note>, <Note: Fourth test note>],
}
```

I'm trying to access each of the note objects inside a django template, and having a helluva time navigating to them. In short, I'm not sure how to extract by index in django templating.

Current template code is:

```
<h3>Notes</h3>
{% for year in notes %}
    {{ year }} # Works fine
    {% for note in notes.year %}
        {{ note }} # Returns blank
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

If I replace {% for note in notes.year %} with {% for note in notes.2010 %} things work fine, but I need that '2010' to be dynamic.

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
<h3>Notes</h3>
{% for year, notes in notes.items %}
    {{ year }}
    {% for note in notes %}
        {{ note }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: rapturous applause/standing ovation/throws underpants

Many thanks. ...I just spent hours on that. ;-)

Comment: I looked at the documentation and didn't recognise the importance of ".items".  Thanks for pointing this out!