# How to extract multiple values of a list of python dictionary (i.e. extract all the values for one key)?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, django-templates

My dictionary looks like this.

```
m_dict = {}  
m_dict.setdefault(ekey1, []).append(m_name)  
m_dict.setdefault(ekey2, []).append(u_r)  
m_dict.setdefault(ekey3, []).append(quan)  
m_dict.setdefault(ekey4, []).append(u_u)  
m_dict.setdefault(ekey5, []).append(r_r)  
m_dict.setdefault(ekey6, []).append(pr)
```

There are multiple values for each key, i.e. values are appended as a list of items.

> My question is how would i extract separately each of those list values for a single key?

For example `ekey5` has values like:

```
[a', Decimal('80'), Decimal('80'), u', Decimal('0'), Decimal('0.95')]
```

So how do I extract each value of `ekey5` in a separate line?

And then how to show it in django template?

Comment: You can also add your items to dictionary in much easier way. `m_dict['ekey1'] = [1, 2, 3, ...]`  and you can do it in a loop.

Comment: yes i know but i am fetching those items from database and then putting into dict. that's why doing like this. it was just a part of my whole thing. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

To do this in a Django template should be very similar to the equivalent Python, based on [answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002728/iterating-dictionary-indexes-in-django-templates)

The following should be identical to [garmoncheg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15850516/745)

```
{% for key, value in m_dict.items %}
    {% for item in value %}
        {{ item }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: yeh i have already tried and it worked perfectly! thanks a lot. :)